# Music Videos on Plex on Synology

Tags: synology, plex

I have Plex running on a Synology and I am trying to add Music Videos that I have downloaded. I have followed the instructions from Plex but nothing seems to be happening. I am adding videos as a Global Music Videos Folder. I have specified the Global Folder as follows:

```
/volume1/video/Music Videos/
```

Since this method does not associate this folder with a library specifically, how do I know if it is working? Will they just show up when I search for them? If so, my Plex does not seem to be detecting the videos...

Comment: You need to direct an extra library to that directory so that plex will scan it. So youll probably have "TV Shows", "Movies", "Music Videos".

Comment: What type of library should it be?

Comment: In case anybody comes here from Google, here's the "official guide":
https://support.plex.tv/articles/205568377-adding-local-artist-and-music-videos/

Comment: Hey @MaxMatti - back when I posted this I had tried using that guide but it didn't quite work as well as the guide made it seem like it would - although maybe they have improved it since then -